# Is there any way that I can free up memory in the java code that is generated to bind C code via JNI/JNA?

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, jna

I am using a java library that use JNA to bind to the original C library (That library is called Leptonica). I encountered a situation where free(data) has to be called in the C code to free up the memory. But, is there any function in java that I can free up the memory?

**In the C code**

```
void ImageData::SetPixInternal(Pix* pix, GenericVector<char>* image_data) {
  l_uint8* data;
  size_t size;
  pixWriteMem(&data, &size, pix, IFF_PNG);
  pixDestroy(&pix);
  image_data->init_to_size(size, 0);
  memcpy(&(*image_data)[0], data, size);
  free(data);
}
```

The function pixWriteMem() will create and allocate memory to the "data", which you need to do free(data) to free up the memory later.

In Java code, I can only access pixWriteMem(), not the SetPixInternal(), so I have no way to free up the "data", which create a memory leak.

Comment: Unless you have specific objects you can clear out, no, and even then, you need to wait for the garbage collector to clean it up for you.

Comment: Everyone else keep talking about the garbage collector and Java's memory. Notice that the OP is talking about C code being called in Java, an dnotice the JNI tag. This is not as simple as letting the garbage collector clean up.

Comment: Your `c` code there is nothing like the real thing, please cut/paste properly.

Comment: I agree with @KevinDTimm. I think there is more to this question than we are aware.

Comment: @KevinDTimm ,Aaron, yes, I will edit the C code. Since the original code involve multiple functions, so that why I make it pretty simple. I will repharse it. And yes, this problem is not as simple as letting garbage colelctor to clean up. I have already tried system.gc() and it is not working

Comment: If your JNA mapping provides you with a `Pointer` to the data that needs to be free, then you can use JNA to map to `free` (or use `Native.free()`) to free the memory.  However, you should clarify your question to indicate what calls you're making in Java.

Comment: @technomage I'm looking at the JNA javadocs, and I don't see a `Native.free()`. The closest thing I see is a `Native.ffi_free_closure()`.

Comment: [`Native.free()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#free-long-), provided as a convenience to access the libc function of the same name.  Even if there weren't, it's trivial to map a libc `free` with whatever signature you want, as long as the argument can be converted to the appropriately-sized pointer value.

Answer (score 6):

The other comments and answers here all seem to be suggesting that you just rely on the garbage collector or tell the garbage collector to run. That **is not** the correct answer for memory allocated in C and being used in Java via JNI.

It looks like that `execution()` **does** free the memory. The last line you show us is `free(data)`. Still, to answer your the question as you asked it, the answer is "not directly." If you have the ability to add to the C code, you could create another C function which frees the data and then call that using JNI. Perhaps there is more that we are not seeing which relates better to your concern about the memory leak?

Also, be careful about freeing memory allocated by a library you are using. You should make sure that the library doesn't still need it and is leaking it before you go trying to free it.

And now back to memory management in general...

Java is indeed a garbage-collected language. This means that you do not specifically delete objects. Instead, you make sure there are no references to it, then the garbage collector takes care of the memory management. This does not mean that Java is free from memory leaks, as there are ways to accidentally keep a reference hanging around such that the object never gets garbage collected. If you have a situation like this, you might want to read up on [the different kinds of references in Java (strong/weak/etc.)](https://www.rallydev.com/blog/engineering/java-references-strong-soft-weak-phantom).

Again, this **is not** the problem here. This is a C/Java hybrid, and the code in question is in C being called by Java. In C, you allocate the memory you want to use and then you need to `free` the memory yourself when you are done with it. Even if the C code is being run by Java via the JNI, *you are still responsible for your own memory*. You cannot just `malloc()` a bunch of memory and expect the Java garbage collector to know when to clean it up. Hence the OP's question.

If you need to add the functionality yourself to do a `free`, even without the source code for the C part, you might still be able to write your own C interface for freeing the memory if you have access to the pointer to the memory in question. You could write basically a tiny library that just frees the memory for you, make the JNI interface for it, and pass the pointer to that. If you go this route then, depending on your OS, you might need to guarantee that your tiny free library's native code is running in the same process as the rest of the native code, or if not the same process then at least that the process you run it from has write access to the memory owned by the other code's process; this memory/process issue is probably not an issue in your case, but I'm throwing it out there for completeness.

Comment: Downvoter: if I said something wrong, please let me know what it is so that I can fix it. I don't want to be spreading misinformation.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it seem like there is no way except changing the C code?

Comment: If it was allocated in C (as in, `malloc()` or an equivalent), then yes, somehow some way it needs eventually to be freed in C. Even if you want to manage it from Java, you still need to do something in C then expose that C functionality to Java to call via JNI.

Comment: I should elaborate on that: Java *cannot even know* when you want C-allocated memory to be freed, technically. In C, it is possible (easy?) to write code in such a way that no garbage collector would ever know when to free it. `int* myPointer; void initN() { myPointer = malloc(sizeof(int*)); }` How do you know when to free that? Even if the Java object calling this gets GCed, some other Java object might use `myPointer` via JNI and expect it to still be there. You just never know, and neither can Java, so the C programmer needs to handle the memory; but possibly by just exposing free to Java.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the only way to solve it is to ask the C develop to add the function and then Java JNI can call it to free memory.

Comment: @RockTheStar Depending on your situation, that might be the only way. Do you have any way at all to access a pointer to the memory you are concerned about? Even without library source code, you might still be able to write your own C interface for freeing the memory if you have access to that pointer. You could write basically a tiny library that just frees the memory for you, make the JNI interface for it, and pass the pointer to that...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

> In Java code, I can only access createData(), not the excution(), so I have no way to free up the "data", which create a memory leak.

Then it sucks to be you.

Seriously, if you want to free memory allocated by a native method and not freed before that method returns, then you need to maintain a handle of some kind on that memory and later pass it to another native method that will free the memory.  If you do not presently have such a native method available, then you'll need to create one.

The other question is how to ensure that the needed native method is invoked.  Relying on users to invoke it, directly or indirectly, leaves you open to memory leaks should users fail to do so.  There are two main ways to solve that problem:

- Give your class a finalizer that ensures the memory is freed.  This is the core use case for finalizers, but even so, there are good reasons to prefer to avoid writing them.  The other alternative is to
- Create a reference object (`SoftReference`, `WeakReference`, or `PhantomReference`), associate the reference with a mechanism for freeing the native-allocated memory belonging to the referenced Java object (but not *via* that object), and register that object with a reference queue.  The reference will be enqueued when the object is GC'd, at which point you know to free the native-allocated memory.

That does not necessarily mean that you should prevent users from explicitly freeing the memory, for with enough bookkeeping you can track whether anything still needs to be freed at any given time.  Allowing users to release resources explicitly may help keep your overall resource usage lower.  But if you want to avoid memory leaks then you need to have a fallback.

Comment: Thanks John. Actually, I am not sure if I understand what you suggest. Can you elaborate on it? Thanks.

Comment: @RockTheStar, you need to have or create a Java class whose instances are responsible for the native-allocated memory.  They need to keep copies of the pointers to allocated blocks, perhaps converted to Java `long`s.  You need to create a suitably-initialized instance each time you cause native allocation to be performed.  Supposing you choose the first option, which is a lot easier to write, you would give that class a `finalize()` method which is responsible for freeing the memory.  It is possible that you will need to write a new native method for it to use for that purpose.

Comment: OK. I guess it is not an easy fix.

Answer (score -2):

No there is no function like C's free() in Java. But you can suggest garbage collector to run by calling System.gc()

Comment: It isn't useful to run the GC for JNI memory unless that memory is managed by a Java object with a `finalize` method that calls the native C code to free the memory. That would work, to a point and subject the caveats that come with `finalize`, but it is one of the standard use cases for finalization.

Comment: ok i misunderstood the question. My comment is invalid in case of JNI/JNA.